# How to use a project template on git?

Tags: git, templates

Suppose one has a git repository containing an empty project template. Now, one wants to use this template for a new git project with the same github account.

What I have tried:

```
git clone https://github.com/user12345/empty-project.git new_project
```

Then, I have created the new repository `new_project` on github, and:

```
cd new_project
git remote add origin https://github.com/user12345/new_project.git
```

But it raises the error:

```
error: remote origin already exists.
```

Comment: You have to either remove origin first or modify the existing origin, since it was automatically added when you cloned the template

Comment: Replace the remote url? `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/user12345/new_project.git`

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes it solved the solution I was trying to come with. But is there a more canonical way of forking a template into the same github account?

Comment: Git doesn’t have forking

Comment: @evolutionxbox Ah! Forking is a Github feature only... This is why I was confused.

Comment: @pietrodito yes, sorry. I didn't finish my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to remove the original origin and add the new one.

```
$ git remote remove origin
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/user12345/new_project.git
```

Or use

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/user12345/new_project.git
```

Comment: Or use `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/user12345/new_project.git`?